# Android fastScroll on the left

Tags: android, position, fastscroll

Is it possible to set fastScroll on the left instead of right?
like here: http://smartphoneblogging.com/wp-content/gallery/asus-eeepad-transformer-tf101-android-4-0-ics/asus_transformer_tf101_android_4_0_ics_contacts.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 listView.setVerticalScrollbarPosition(ListView.SCROLLBAR_POSITION_LEFT);
```